# How to fix WebStorm 2016.1.1 function syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, webstorm

I just upgraded to WebStorm 2016.1.1 and all of my functions and function calls are white. I've messed with several settings and themes.

Anyone run into this and fixed it?

Comment: what editor color scheme do you use? Please provide screenshot that shows up your issue

Comment: have you found solution? I have the same with 2016.3

Comment: I have not. I downgraded to an earlier version.